# 400 Bad Request error when simulating login with Postman on ASP.NET Core Web Application with individual user accounts stored in-app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

Postman returns a 400 Bad Request error when trying to simulate a login request to an ASP.NET Core Web Application that has an authentication of individual user accounts stored in-app.

However, I am able to log in when using the default application template generated by Visual Studio. Using Chrome DevTools, it seems like the request is as follows:

- Request URL: *application*/Identity/Account/Login
- Request Method: POST
- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Form Data:

  - Input.Email: *user's email address*
  - Input.Password: *user's password*
  - __RequestVerificationToken: *token*
  - Input.RememberMe: *user's selection of either true or false*

I have unsuccessfully tried to simulate this using Postman as follows: [Postman request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuVeL.png) and [Postman request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P11Lc.png)

Postman returns a 400 Bad Request error without any additional information: [Postman response with 400 error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhLYB.png)

Please could you help me determine what is wrong in my request when attempting to simulate the login with Postman?

**Edit:** I did not write any custom code for this. It is the default template generated in Visual Studio. I tried looking for the function that gets called when I use the built-in login page

When I add a scaffold "Identity" to the project using Visual Studio, the login page is named *Login.cshtml* and it uses the default LoginModel. When I tried to debug with a breakpoint, I see that it calls a function named *OnPostAsync* in the LoginModel class.

However, when I use Postman, the breakpoint is not reached. Therefore, I think this may be because my current request structure is incorrect

Comment: Details are not enough. Please post your API method code. It might help to find out the issue.

Comment: @shalithasenanayaka, I did not write any custom code for this. It is the default template generated in Visual Studio. I tried looking for the function that gets called when I use the built-in login page. When I add a scaffold "Identity" to the project using Visual Studio, the login page is named _Login.cshtml_ and it uses the default _LoginModel_. When I tried to debug with a breakpoint, I see that it calls this function: _OnPostAsync_ in the _LoginModel_ class. However, when I use Postman, the breakpoint is not reached. Therefore, I think this may be because the request structure is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Sometime this may help. Decorate your PageModel class with `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]`. The key is the Order parameter. The built-in `[ValidateAntiforgeryToken]` has an order of 1000, and therefore explicitly setting `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` to anything greater than 1000 should resolve the issue.

refer - [Disabling antiforgery token verification](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7012)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works. However, is it correct to ignore anti-forgery tokens? Will this not make the web application vulnerable to Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks?

Comment: Actually not recommend but consider your requirement, this is the only way I know. If you want to access the methods in externally, implement a Web API method.If you found the answer. please mark as the right answer it may help for someone.